# Cells.Address Returns What?

Tags: vba, excel

What does Cells.Address return?  I tried to put it in a Range variable and it came back with a type mismatch error.

```
 Dim A As Range
 A = Cells(1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

When I put the function into a MsgBox, it returns A1.  How can I turn this into a range?

Comment: To turn Cells(1,1) into a Range: `Set A = Cells(1,1)`.

Comment: Well that was easy.  Thanks

Comment: There is something called MSDN, also there is Google. How difficult would it be to type `Cells.Address` on google to find out what it's returning...

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comments me how.  I looked it up and didn't see where it said what it returns.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174749(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Address()" function returns a string, hence you can see "A1" in MsgBox. To convert the address back to Range,

```
Dim strAddress As String

strAddress = "A1"
Set A = Sheet1.Range(strAddress)
```

Then A is the Range object referencing Cell(1,1).